# Does the RAM burn out forever or is it reusable after some time?

Tags: dapp, ram, staking

I would like to purchase RAM to do some actions such as smart contract executions as well as token transfers. On Ethereum, you would have to pay for gas and the gas burns forever.

1. Am I going to be able to re-use the RAM for a Dapp I am building (so unlike ETH gas, it is not wasted forever) ?
2. How much time does it take for a RAM to recover once it is used-up (if it does recover at all) ?
3. If RAM does not recover over some period of time, and if RAM does recover, what does it take for RAM to recover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER TAKEN FROM:
https://np.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8hmpj0/ram_trading/dyl6r5g/

> When you "buy" ram you stake for it, using eos, which locks it up while you have the ram. You pay a price determined by the system based
>   on the current % of ram in use (staked for by others). You pay a 1%
>   eos fee when doing this.
>
> Later, when you unstake your ram, you pay ANOTHER 1% fee, and then
>   your account is either increased or reduced by the difference in price
>   from the time you bought.
>
> So if you buy ram early, then more people buy ram, and then you sell
>   the ram, your eos balance will be higher after you sell... making you
>   extra eos. This is the speculative nature of ram trading.
>
> If you want to try to play in this market, be careful. Any increase in
>   RAM capacity by the BPs will decrease the cost of ram, and of course
>   even the announcment of a side chain being delpoyed by the BPs of the
>   mainchain will dump the price of ram since that is also an increase in
>   capacity overall (causing people to unstake their ram on the main
>   chain).
>
> Hope this helps.